# How can I create a form with unknown number of columns and rows?

Tags: django, django-forms

I don't know if I will be able to explain this very well, so please bear with me, and I will update where/when needed as much as I can.

---

I have a Django app that is designed to take in data from users for products that we need to configure. The products are split into main categories of main products, which are then further split by customer. Main products have default settings, and customer products have SOME of these settings changed, plus some others not listed by the main product. Each customer may have multiple variations of the product too.

**Example of products:**

```
Main Product A
|
|-> Customer A Product A1
|-> Customer A Product A2
|
|-> Customer B Product A1
|-> Customer B Product A2

Main Product B
|
|-> Customer A Product B1
|-> Customer A Product B2
|
|-> Customer B Product B1
|-> Customer B Product B2
```

What I need/want, is a table for staff to enter the needed settings for a given customer, without the app knowing how many settings are needed, and how many customer products there are, in advance.

Example:

| Setting | Product A1 | + |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Low Power | TRUE |  |
| Delayed Start | 5 seconds |  |
| + |  |  |

If the user was to then hit the plus (just an example method, open to suggestions here too), another column would appear where they can enter the Product name (E.G. "Product A2") and start editing the data for that product against the same Settings value:

| Setting | Product A1 | Product A2 | + |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Low Power | TRUE | FALSE |  |
| Delayed Start | 5 seconds | 5 seconds |  |
| + |  |  |  |

Then when ready, and the form is saved, the form would submit like two separate forms, where "Setting" is repeated in both, and the Product specific columns are separated, as below:

```
Product:
Product A1

Settings:
Low Power = TRUE
Delayed Start = 5 seconds
```

```
Product:
Product A2

Settings:
Low Power = FALSE
Delayed Start = 5 seconds
```

---

**Firstly**, is the above possible? Logically, I can see it being possible, but I am too new to the framework to know where to start looking for the solution.

**Secondly**, if not possible as above, I can take in the products before this page, and then have a known number of columns on this page, but it would still need to work the same way, that they share the first column when submitting, and I would still not know the number of rows. If this reduces the complexity, then this is definitely an option.

**Also**, I understand this might be read as "do my project for me", and that could not be further from the truth. I want to understand how to do this, not just get it working and forget about it. I need to be able to support this app going forward too. So if you are even able to help me understand what I need to look up to get going in the right direction, I will still be incredibly grateful!

---

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is a [Formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/formsets/)

The default way that these display is the transpose of your illustration: clicking the "add" button creates another instance of the form at the bottom.

You can dynamically construct a form if you want to use a formset view to implement "add a set of entities of type X" where X was previously chosen by the user, and its relevant fields are determined at run-time.

Another approach I've seen (but not written!) is to construct the data grid using a front-end framework and POST it as JSON. Django can decode this JSON into  Python data using a form with a single JSONField, and then process that data. Note that if you do this, you have to validate it to your satisfaction. You can't trust anything arriving from a possible hostile actor performing a POST. Django forms provide a good framework for validation, even if you never display them. Just instantiate them with a dict of unvalidated data and check `form.is_valid()`

I've stuck to generalities here. Hopefully this will give you some pointers to be getting on with.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, thank you, I'll look up some front-end frameworks that might work best for this. I hadn't thought about not using Django's forms, but treat it more like an API to intake the data. Thank you.